# Cognito session sharing between subdomain

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I have app1.domain.com and app2.domain.com, now if I log in to app1.domain.com and go to app2.domain.com, I should be able to access app2.domain.com without logging into app2. is there a way to achieve it using Cognito?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Cognito's Hosted UI for this purpose.

1. Configure **App1** to route unauthenticated users to the Cognito Hosted UI for sign-in.
2. Once the user logs in, cookies are added to the browser for Cognito Hosted UI domain.
3. Set up the second app, **App2**, to use the same Cognito Hosted UI.
4. When the second app user opens the page, they are also redirected to the Cognito Hosted UI. Since the, Cognito Hosted UI already has a user session from app 1 (via Cookies), it will re-use the session, and return the app user to callback URL of second app (via Authorization Code flow). The second app, can now login the user.
5. Don't forget to use Cognito's Global Signout option when signing out of the app.

> Disclaimer: Once a user has logged into the app, each app will keep its own cookies for user session management.